# Any comics or other media where Kara got to raise Kal-El as she was supposed to do?

Tags: dc, superman, supergirl

Almost every source on Supergirl states that Kara was supposed to look after Kal-El on Earth.

It would be really interesting to see how a young teenager with superpowers manages to look after a baby while hiding from the government(s) and learning how to live on Earth.

I've seen a number of Elseworlds or Alternate Universe stories on Superman, but I've not seen any story where Kara got to fulfill her mission.

> Is there any official comics or other media where Kara got to raise Kal-El on Earth?

By 'other media' I mean films (though I know where are not any), tv-series episodes (including animated), or anything at all that is sanctioned by DC. Not that I've seen any fanfiction like this either.

Comment: That's only been true since 2004 (according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supergirl)).  Up to then, she was always younger than Superman, and in fact was only born after Krypton had exploded.

Comment: @ibid, sorry, the question was bad

Comment: Actually, the closest to this I can think of has nothing to do with Supergirl - it's the "Letita Lerner, Superman's Baby-Sitter" from the _Bizarro_Comics_ hardback. Kyle Baker was the primary creator. Just a story about an average teenage girl babysitting a very young (at most toddler) Clark Kent.

Comment: @RDFozz, thanks for the reference. Might be funny to read

Comment: It is. It was actually supposed to be published in (I think) an Elseworlds special - until one of the higher-ups got a look at it, and decided that they couldn't publish a comic with a baby in a microwave. As I recall, the comic had actually been printed, and the full run was pulped. Given the price differential between an 80-page comic and a hardcover, it finally saw the light of day "safely" there. And yes, it's utterly intended to be funny, and succeeds brilliantly,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No (for now)

Comics wise, I haven't been able to find anything. [Alternative versions of Supergirl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_versions_of_Supergirl). There are several different versions where she is either Powergirl (instead of Supergirl) and versions where Superman never existed, but not one where she arrives ahead of (or at the same time as) Kal-el and raises him.

[image]

There are also no tv or film (live action or animated) where her story is told from her arriving to Earth ahead of Superman.

Of course, originally Supergirl wasn't his cousin, but was a survivor from Argo that her father sent to Earth hoping Kal-el would take care of her.

[image]

There might be some fan fiction (a few results come up on fanfiction.net which suggest that at least one person has written a story where Kara arrives first). Those links seem to be broken for me, so I can't confirm they really exist.